# Microphone Pre Amp Book?

Tags: amplifier, audio, microphone

I'm wondering if there's a book that discusses resistors, capacitors, inductors, transistors, transformers, impedance, op amps, power supplies, and the general circuitry of a microphone pre amp. Thank you!

Comment: "The Art of Electronics" by Hurowitz and Hill doesn't address preamps directly, but it has what you need.

Comment: Small Signal Audio Design and Self on Audio, both by Douglas Self are good if you already have an understanding of analogue electronics.

Answer (score 2):

There are many, being as a mic pre is just a low noise small signal amplifier working down at near DC.

Basically any good analog electronics text book dealing with small signal design will do for the fundamentals, and you can go almost as far down the rabbit hole of trying to get ever lower excess noise as you like.

For a rather no nonsense hands on view Doug Selfs 'Small signal audio design' is not bad, also Henry Ott and Howard Johnson fir the interference mitigation methods you will need.

AD/Linear have decent app notes on current and voltage noise, also resistor noise and the trade offs.

THAT corp have some decent app notes as well (Also some sand that is good enough to make rolling your own not worth the pain).

The AES is worth joining for their on line library, in particular for the stuff on correct earthing, EMC and the dangers (to the be junctions) of phantom power accidents and how to limit the damage.